# Exercise: pointers and references in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Is this correct:

a) Pointer p1 to a char:

```
char* p1;
```

b) A constant pointer p2 to a char:

```
char* const p2;
```

c) pointer p3 to a constant char:

```
const char* p3;
```

d) A constant pointer p4 to a constant char:

```
const char* const p4;
```

e) A reference r1 to a char:

```
char & r1;
```

f) A reference r2 to a constant char:

```
const char& r2;
```

Would you please notify me any mistakes?

Comment: All correct. But for C) I prefer (and its a preference thing) `char const* p3;` If you read left to write now it matches the question. Similarly for D) `char const* const p4;` F) `char const& r2;`

Answer (score 4):

They are all correct. I can't see any mistakes :-)

Answer (score 3):

No mistakes, everything is correct.)

Comment: +1: @laika: Everything is correct except maybe that some of your declarations are illegal because they require an initializer. But I don't think that's relevant

Answer (score 2):

Everything looks correct. A rule of thumb to use in C/C++ is to read it right to left. 
For example: const char *p is a pointer( * ) to a character that is constant/constant character.